# Finite field and map

Tags: group-theory, field-theory

[image]Good morning 
If $F$ a finite field and $n$ positive integer ,what mean the following map :
$$
k:F^n  \rightarrow F.
$$
that mean if $v\in F^n$ vector equal $v=\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\}$ ,then the map transform to a single value of the field $F$.
Example $F_3=\{0,1,2\}$ ,$n=3$ and $v=\{2,1,1\} \in F_3^n$,then the map $k$ will map this vector to a single element of $F_3$ for example $2\in F_3 $?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us what context you're seeing this map in?

Comment: OK i have put a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be analogous to a map from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R$. There are many such maps, but an important class is taking the dot product with a fixed vector $v\in\Bbb R^n$. (These are nice maps because they are vector space homomorphisms.) The same construction holds for any fields, including finite fields.

For example, with $F=\Bbb F_3$ and $n=3$, you could fix a vector like $v=(2,0,1)\in \Bbb F_3^3$, and define the function $k\colon \Bbb F_3^3 \to \Bbb F_3$ by
$$
k(x) = x\cdot v, \quad\text{or}\quad k\big( (x_1,x_2,x_3) \big) = (x_1,x_2,x_3)\cdot(2,0,1) = 2x_1+x_3.
$$
Note that in this example, $k\big( (2,1,1) \big) = (2,1,1)\cdot(2,0,1) = 4+0+1 = 2$ in $\Bbb F_3$.

Comment: OK i will put a picture from when i have this expression i think is the same with your result can you see the picture then tel me if the same or  not

Comment: I hop that the definition and your explanation is the same ,thank you so much.